# AS3: Can I get MovieClip within a MovieClip from External Flash file Dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want access MovieClips Dynamically from the external flash file.
There are 5 MovieClips named Loader_1_mc, Loader_2_mc,....  Loader_5_mc like so. Each of this movieClip contain 5 movieClips by named acc_1,acc_2,...... acc_5 like.
How Can I access From the swf file. i tried few steps within nested loop

```
accChrome["Loader_"+bInd+"_mc"].["acc_"+sVal].y = 780;
```

and,

```
accChrome["Loader_"+bInd+"_mc"]["acc_"+sVal].y = 780;
```

and

```
MovieClip(accChrome["Loader_"+bInd+"_mc"])["mask_"+sVal].y = 780;
```

and

```
accChrome["Loader_"+bInd+"_mc.mask_"+sVal].y = 780;
```

i wont get it..
Please Help me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data-type of your `accChrome` object? Is it just a MovieClip? Or a derived class from a MovieClip?

Answer (score 0):

[Accessing Movieclips in movieclips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371495/accessing-movieclips-in-movieclips) (Stack Overflow Question)

```
var clipInClip:Acc; // class name is Acc in this case, but its whatever
clipInClip = ((this.Loader_1_mc as MovieClip).acc_1 as Acc);
```

clipInClip should properly hold acc_1 in this example. As for looping through using parts of strings, look at dthoughts post on this page... http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?259717-eval-in-actionscript-3 (3rd post)

This isn't too great of an answer, so if you get stuck, ask!